# LibGdx Game Development Essentials, Chapter two of this book states my scrolling textures should be infinite. mine only show two then it ends

Tags: java, libgdx

I keep failing on getting it to scroll infinatly, any one else had the same problem.
The game is ThrustCopter and it should scroll TextureBelow and TextureAbove.
I am ony developing for Android. I'm sure the problem lies somewhere in this snippet of code.

```
public void updateScene() {
    float graphicsDeltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    terrainOffset -= 100*graphicsDeltaTime;
}

public void resetScene() {
    terrainOffset = 0;
}

public void drawScene() {
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();

    batch.disableBlending();
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0);
    batch.enableBlending();

    batch.draw(terrainBelow, terrainOffset, 0);
    batch.draw(terrainBelow, terrainOffset + terrainBelow.getRegionWidth(), 0);

    batch.draw(terrainAbove, terrainOffset, 480 - terrainAbove.getRegionHeight());
    batch.draw(terrainAbove, terrainOffset + terrainAbove.getRegionWidth(), 480 - terrainAbove.getRegionHeight());

    batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're moving two copies of the texture left forever. You should prevent `terrainOffset` from going farther left off the screen than the width of the texture. By using the remainder of dividing out the texture width, you will cause it to seamlessly pop forward by the width of the texture.

I'm assuming these textures are at least as wide as the camera's `viewportWidth`, and *x = 0* aligns with the left edge of the view.

Replace

```
terrainOffset -= 100*graphicsDeltaTime;
```

with

```
terrainOffset = (terrainOffset - 100 * graphicsDeltaTime) % terrainBelow.getRegionWidth();
```

If your two terrain textures have different widths, then you need two `terrainOffset` variables, one for each texture.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, I will now study it and carry on with my progress.